# How to hide an empty block with no results

Tags: views, blocks

The block is generated by Views and I the only field comes from a relationship and is not accessible in the filters, so I can't set a filter.

I have tried to use another field, rewrite the results but the filter only considers that initial value of the field, not the rewritten one.

I suspect I have to do something with a template file, but a precise how-to would be very helpful.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution turned up pretty simple: I had to check the "Require this relationship" option in the relationships settings

Answer (score 0):

try restricting the block's display using "Pages on which this PHP code returns TRUE (experts only)"  and checking for the final re-written value there.