# Hide an entire View Block when query returns no data

Tags: views

I have a view block and - because of the filters being applied - it may show data or may not. If the view's query returns no results, I need to hide the entire block - the `.block` - not just the `.view` or `.view-content`. I've seen [several](https://www.drupal.org/node/1343430) [other](http://www.codeforbidden.com/drupal/tutorials/hide-block-if-view-empty) [questions](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/49208/how-to-hide-an-empty-block-with-no-results) and [pages](http://mzlizz.mit.edu/code-forbidden-hide-block-if-view-empty) that offer solutions but all either don't hide the entire `.block` or just flat out don't work.

The solution that appears to be most discussed uses the `Global: Null` contextual filter, but that **always** hides the entire block regardless of any other condition. In fact, it doesn't even run the query when this filter is active. I need the block to be hidden if and only if the query returns no results.

I have the default, barebones Drupal 7 installed with only Bartik, CTools and Views so I am sure there aren't any other conflicts coming in from the theme or other modules.

Comment: did you ever find a solution for this?

Comment: @Randell Sorry. I cant recall. I don't even remember what site I was working on back then.

Answer (score -1):

**One of the solution is:**

Under *FIELDS:* click each field and in the *"No results text"* area, check the *"hide if empty"* box.

This will allow the field not to show if there is nothing actually there to show. But will not affect how the block itself displays on the page.

**Another solution for this is :**

> 1. Go to the advanced tab of you view
> 2. Add contextual filters
> 3. Select Global: Null
> 4. When the filter value is NOT available: Select 'Hide view'

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. As I stated in my question, when I attempt this solution, the block is ALWAYS hidden. I only want the block to be hidden when the query returns no data. Can you confirm that this solution will only hide the block when the query returns no results?

Comment: ummm...i am also not so sure about this may be you can try the first solution also that i have mentioned

Comment: Unfortunately,no. The first suggestion does not hide the whole block.